# Excel VBA Read Only supersedes BeforeSave

Tags: excel, vba, before-save

I have code that incorporates business logic for saving documents (Excel 365) to ensure proper naming convention, file locations etc etc as a Sub Workbook_BeforeSave

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True  ''Cancels the Save from the button push or Ctrl+S
Application.EnableEvents = False
'' code code code
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that if the file is opened as Read-Only (as most will be) Excel will prompt that "the file is Read-Only" (pic a) and go to the Save As screen in the File Ribbon (pic b). The `Workbook_BeforeSave` sub won't kick in until the SAVE button is pressed. It also won't move off this screen even after the sub has run.
Is there any way to either:

1. Get in front of the Read-Only prompt ... or
2. Write some code to move off the Save As screen?

[MS Read-Only promt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRSFS.jpg) (pic a)
[Save As Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFMWq.jpg) (pic b)

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect approach but try this.
This will cancel the save completely even after pressing the Save button, you can add your own save code.

Edit: Just realized that the code below does not stop the Read Only Alert, but when you click Save it cancels the Save and Closes the Save As Menu. However, when they use Ctrl+S the Send Keys {ESC} triggers a Ctrl+ESC which opens the Star Menu...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Disable Read Only Alert
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Disable Events
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Cancel Save
    Cancel = True
    'Do whatever code you need in here
    '
    'Mark Workbook as Saved, allowing for the file to close without an alert even if not saved
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    'Send Escape Key to leave Save As Menu
    Application.SendKeys "{ESC}", 1
    'Enable Events
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    'Enable Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The `Application.SendKeys "{ESC}", 1` worked great for getting off the Save As screen. It solves the UI issue of the user pressing the SAVE button into infinity thinking nothing has happened. Unfortunately `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` does not get in before Excel's "Read-Only" warning. I'll take it as a win. Again, huge thanks!

Comment: response to the edit:  I'm not finding that the issue you mentioned with the `{ESC}` is opening the Start Menu in my environment. It's placed right before `End Sub` and working great.